# How to implement the cancel button for edit functionality in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, edit, cancel-button

i have used edit button. after editing i have save and cancel button .save button is working as i expected but not the cancel button.
      if  i click the cancel button after trying to edit, it should show the previous text. can anyone please help me 
js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/F7K63/143/

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>
            <span ng-hide="item.editing">{{item.name}} <button  ng-click="editItem(item)">Edit</button></span>
            <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-model="item.name"  autofocus />
            <button ng-show="item.editing" ng-click="doneEditing(item)">Save</button>
             <button ng-show="item.editing" ng-click="Cancel(item)">Cancel</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You should make a copy of the item that you want to edit. If you press cancel replace the origin with the copy.

Comment: can you show in the above jsfiddle please

Comment: This fiddle may help: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lbjuhsq/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a copy of your object you want to edit. If you press cancel replace the origin. See the  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7K63/145/)

```
$scope.editItem = function (item) {
    item.editing = true;
    item.backupName = angular.copy(item.name);
}

$scope.doneEditing = function (item) {
    item.editing = false;
    delete item.backupName;
    //do some background ajax calling for persistence...
};
$scope.Cancel = function (item) {
    item.editing = false;
    item.name = angular.copy(item.backupName);
    delete item.backupName;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest option is to edit your $scope.eidtItem and $scope.Cancel functions.

```
$scope.editItem = function (item) {
    item.editing = true;
    item.oldName = item.name;
}
```

...

```
$scope.Cancel = function (item) {
    item.editing = false;
    item.name = item.oldName;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F7K63/147/

Comment: I've included a jsfiddle. It should be OK. Please check it.

Comment: @Christoph item.oldName and item.name are Strings, and they are distinct properties of item object. I think it's OK. What problem do you see?
You can see item object contents here: http://jsfiddle.net/F7K63/148/
You don't need to use angular.copy to copy single String.

Comment: Yes you're right, with strings it doesn't matters. But i think it should work with all objects ;)

Comment: In that case it's clear that we operate on Strings (the value is held in input). So I think using angular.copy is an overkill.